# show the incompleteness of $(a,b)$, $(a,b]$, and $[a,b)$ by exhibiting cauchy sequences that do not converge.

Tags: general-topology

The book I am using is Principles of Topology by Fred H. Croom Exercise 3.7

Question 1)

Show the incompleteness of $(a,b)$, $(a,b]$, and $[a,b)$ by exhibiting Cauchy sequences that do not converge.

I know that a metric space $(X,d)$ is complete if every Cauchy sequence in $X$ converges to a point in $X$.

Answer (score 3):

- $u_n = a+ \frac{b-a}{n+2}$ for $(a,b)$
- $u_n = a+ \frac{b-a}{n+2}$ for $(a,b]$
- $u_n = b - \frac{b-a}{n+2}$ for $[a,b)$

Comment: Why bother with the $n+2$ ? So that all terms of each sequence are in the required interval. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

$a+\frac{b-a}{n}$ works for the first two.

$b-\frac{b-a}{n}$ works for the third.

Comment: First one does not work for the first interval as for $n=1$ its value is $b$, which is not in $(a,b)$.

Answer (score 0):

It is important to understand that the answer is essentially the same for all three questions.  Let's take $[0,1)$ as a prototypical example. This space is incomplete because it ought to have $1$, and you can find a sequence that converges to $1$, except there is no $1$, it has been left out.  So a sequence that would converge to $1$ in a larger space, say $[0,1]$ or $[0,2)$, does not converge in $[0,1)$, even though it still has the Cauchy property.